# Timeout issue on AWS Web app deploying .ebextensions config don't work

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-deployment, amazon-rds, connection-timeout

please help me with starting WAR Spring MVC Web app on AWS (Amazon Web service) 
it fails with connection timeout to database ( to RDS - also Amazon).

I works localy absolutely fine. via tomcat it connects to my RDS and works, 
but when I deploy this war on AWS  - timeout.

I tried to add configs to increase timeout, but seems it is ignored by AWS.

Could you please help ??

structure of WAR file:

```
-META-INF
-WEB-INF
  |- classes
  |- lib
  |- view (*.jsp here)
-.ebextensions
  |- timeout.config
```

timeout.config content:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 1800
```

Logs :
Where  com.books.dao.impl.GenreDAOImpl.findAll(GenreDAOImpl.java:49) my first request to DB.

```
16-Jun-2018 20:24:46.050 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection] with root cause
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:161)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:394)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:474)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:484)
    at com.books.dao.impl.GenreDAOImpl.findAll(GenreDAOImpl.java:49)
```

Security for elasticbeanstalk

[Security Group for elastic bean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7buak.png)

Security for ec2 
[Security Group for EC2 instance where public access failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU4Xm.png)

Comment: What do your security groups look like?

Comment: How can I check it ? 
I created web app via /elasticbeanstalk/ and I can't find setting for secutiry group there

I also set up and EC2 machine, but can;t access it by Public IP/DNS. 
I can show theirs Security group,  but I am not sure that they are related to elasticbeanstal

Comment: Seems I got it, they all are present in EC2

Comment: @Chris Pollard , Question updated

Comment: have you check the security group of your Db? what kind of DB you are using ? is it RDS ? or running MYSQL inside the Instance itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's not an issue of config file not working, its due to security group is blocking for port or not allowing your application to get connected with your Database.

So if you are using RDS Instance then check the **Security Group of your RDS**, and also in which **VPC** it is. Best is just try to ping your RDS Instance and see whether you are getting the reply from it or not.

If you are using Mysql, Running inside your Instance, then just Allow the **port** (3306 for MySQL) in your **EC2 Security Group**. As your **Port** is not open, so AWS won't able to make the connection
In this case, you have to Install Mysql in your Instance if not installed before the deployment.

What happens it when you try with your Local development (Tomcat), So what happens is, in our code, we have mention localhost:3306 as the connection URL and being on the same machine (your development and MySQL) it works fine.